# NSURLSession uploadTaskWithRequest - use block within completion handler

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsurlsession

I have a class which manages all calls to an api. 
It has a method to manage this, lets call this `callAPIMethod:`

This method accepts a `success` and `fail` block.

Inside this method, I call `uploadTaskWithRequest` to make a call to an API.
Within the uploadTaskWithRequest completion handler I'd like to (depending on the result) pass results back through to either the `success` or `fail` blocks.

I'm having some issues with this. It works and is keeping everything super tidy but when I call `callAPIMethod` using the success/fail blocks it's locking up the UI/MainThread rather than being asynchronous as I'd expect.

How should I go about implementing this pattern? Or is there a better way to go about it?

I don't need to support pre-iOS7.

Thanks

Edit: Basic implementation discussed above.

```
- (void)callApiMethod:(NSString *)method withData:(NSString *)requestData as:(kRequestType)requestType success:(void (^)(id responseData))success failure:(void (^)(NSString *errorDescription))failure {
    [redacted]
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                       fromData:postData
                                              completionHandler:
                                  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                      if (error) {
                                          failure(error.description);
                                      } else {
                                          NSError *jsonError;
                                          id responseData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                                             JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                             options:kNilOptions
                                                             error:&jsonError];
                                          if (jsonError) {
                                              failure(jsonError.description);
                                          } else {
                                              success(responseData);
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }];

    [task resume];
}
```

CallAPI method, used as follows (from a UITableViewController):

```
[apiController callApiMethod:@"users.json?action=token"
                    withData:loginData
                          as:kRequestPOST
                     success:^(id responseData) {
                         if ([responseData isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                             if ([responseData objectForKey:@"token"]) {
                                 //Store token/credentials
                             } else if ([responseData objectForKey:@"error"]) {
                                 //Error
                                 [self displayErrorMessage:[responseData objectForKey:@"error"]];
                                 return;
                             } else {
                                 //Undefined Error
                                 [self displayErrorMessage:nil];
                                 return;
                             }
                         } else {
                             //Error
                             [self displayErrorMessage:nil];
                             return;
                         }

                         //If login success

                     }
                     failure:^(NSString *errorDescription) {
                         [self displayErrorMessage:errorDescription];
                     }];
```

Comment: Edited to add code. Thought it was an acceptable way of doing this so probably doing something completely stupid.

Comment: Good point on dispatching to the main thread. On success I'm pushing a new view controller to the nav stack. Guessing I should dispatch that to the main thread also? `displayErrorMessage` shows an alertView although the UI is locked whether there is an error or not.

Comment: Thanks! As I thought, a stupid mistake. I'd assumed it would have crashed if not on the main thread... instead of just hanging for 10+ seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `NSURLSession` code looks fine. I'd suggest adding some breakpoints so you can identify if it is deadlocking somewhere and if so, where. But nothing in this code sample would suggest any such problem.

I would suggest that you ensure that all UI calls are dispatched back to the main queue. This `NSURLSessionUploadTask` completion handler may be called on a background queue, but all UI updates (alerts, navigation, updating of `UIView` controls, etc.) must take place on the main queue.